# xml に対する sed/jq 的なプログラム

Tags: xml

テキストを sed で処理したり、 json を jq で処理するように、 xml を処理したいと考えているのですが、これに適したプログラムはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XPath で指定したノードを取り出すとかでしたら、 `xmllint` コマンドがなかなかいい感じです。

```
<dict>
    <prop name="foo" value="bar" />
    <prop name="hoge" value="piyo" />
</dict>
```

を `test.xml` として保存しておいて、

```
$ xmllint --xpath "count(/dict/prop)" test.xml
2
$ xmllint --xpath "/dict/prop[1]" test.xml
<prop name="foo" value="bar"/>
$ xmllint --xpath "string(/dict/prop[@name='hoge']/@value)" test.xml
piyo
```

などなど。

### 参考

- [ShellScriptでXMLの内容を取り出す | Opentone Labs.](http://labs.opentone.co.jp/?p=5273)
- [Command line utilities for analyzing XML (xpath and xmllint) | Nishigaya's Tech Blog](http://javaflavor.hopto.org/blog/2013/01/14/xpath-and-xmllint/)

Answer (score 1):

Macを使っていれば、tidyコマンドが便利です。
ターミナルでコマンドを入力するだけです。

test.xmlをターミナルで出力

```
tidy --indent-cdata true -xml -utf8 -i test.xml
```

test.xmlからtest2.xmlに変換

```
tidy --indent-cdata true -xml -utf8 -i　-o test2.xml ./test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

xmllint --xpath

この--xpathが指定できるのは、libxml version 20708 とかですね。
libxml version 20706だと、--xpathが実装されていないので、
Ubuntu10.04だと、10.04で動作する最新がversion 20706なので、
このテクニックは使えないです。